# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] after updating to Android 1.3 RC 3

Tags: android

I just updated my Android Studio to Android 1.3 RC 3 and i'm having this kind of error when i'm trying to run my project. I don't have any error on my codes for the application and i'm using LG G2 for the test of the application.

This is my gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.windows81.nowv2"
        minSdkVersion 'L'
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

}
```

And my Android Manifest is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.windows81.nowv2" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is Android L or above installed on your device ?

Comment: Please remove `minSdkVersion 'L'`. That is an old preview.

Comment: I think Android L is not installed in my device. My device has API 19, but eventhough i changed the Android L to 19, i'm still having this kind of error.